# coin flip program wont run

Tags: c++

The program will not run can anyone help me understand why. It is a coin flip game that is supposed to ask the amount of times you want to flip the coin, ask you if you are calling Heads or tails,  flip it and then say whether you were right or wrong in your guess

```
# include <iostream>
# include <ctime>
# include <cstdlib>
# include <string>
using namespace std;
int tossingtimes()
{
    int tosses;
    cout << "How many tosses will we attempt? " << endl;
    cin >> tosses;

    while(tosses < 1)
    {
        cout << "Error tosses must be greater than or equal to 1. Please submit a correct answer." << endl;
        cin >> tosses;
    }
    return tosses;
}
void H_T ()
{
    char HT;
    cout << "Will you be guessing heads or tails? ('h' or 't')";
    cin >> HT;
    if ( HT = 'h')
    {
        cout << "You chose to select Heads!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You chose to select Tails!";
    }
}
int numHT ()
{
    int num;

    cout << "How many times will " << H_T () << "come up?";
    cin >> num;
    return num;
}
int head_win ()
{
    int heads=0;
    heads++;
    return heads;
}
int tails_win ()
{
    int tails=0;
    tails++;
    return tails;
}
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned) time(0));rand();  
    int result = rand() % 2; 
    while (true) 
    { 
        int tosses_amount, HT, num;
        tosses_amount = tossingtimes();
        H_T ();
        num = numHT();
        cin.ignore (1000, 10); 

        if (tosses_amount == 0) 
            break; 

        for (int i = 0; i < tosses_amount; i++) 
            //random number generator 
        {     
            if (result == 0) 
            {
                int head_win();
                cout << "Heads" << endl;
            }
            else if (result == 1) 
            {
                int tails_win();
                cout << "Tails"<<endl; 
            }

        } 
    } 
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Improve formatting 2. Be more specific (what happens and what did you expect for example)

Comment: What's the error message? "Does not run" isn't an error message.

Comment: Yes, please do fix the formatting.  No one can help you if they can't read it.

Comment: By your count, this program is supposed to do four things. You should develop and test each one alone, before you try to knit them together.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious problem I see is:

```
void H_T() { 
// ...
} 

// ...
cout << "How many times will " << H_T() << "come up?";
```

This attempts to print out the return value from `H_T`, but since `H_T` has void return type, there is no such thing, and compilation will fail.

Glancing through the code, it looks like that's hardly the only one though. I think if I were you, I'd back up and more or less start over. Write little pieces at a time, and verify that each does what you intend before going to the next.

Comment: +1 for "Write little pieces at a time and verify that each does what you intend before going to the next."  This philosophy would have saved me a lot of time at the university. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In `void H_T()` you have:

```
if ( HT = 'h')
```

that assigns the value `'h'` to `HT` which will always evaluate to true. You want `==` instead to test for equality.

Unfortunately you don't keep track of what the user selected anywhere in the code...

Comment: Also, the OP may need to use either `tolower` or `toupper` to reduce checking for both 'H' and 'h'.  With `tolower`, the OP only needs to check for 'h'.

Answer (score 0):

on first look..

```
int head_win ()
    {
    int heads=0;
    heads++;
    return heads;
    }
    int tails_win ()
    {
    int tails=0;
    tails++;
    return tails;
    }
```

head_win() will return always 1 and tails_win() too..

```
int head_win();       this doesn t mean nothing..
```

you have to declare a variable :

```
int wins = head_win();
```

Comment: -1, the OP needs to declare the `heads` and `tails` as `static`, otherwise they disappear upon exiting of the function.

Comment: Here's an example: `int head_win() { static int heads = 0; heads++; return heads; }`.   Another issues with this techniques is that the program must be restarted in order to initialize the variables.

Comment: yeah ok! i understand  what is your point but what is wrong on my  answer?! i said that the function return always '1' if you declare `int heads = 0` inside..this is a matter of fact. and this means that he should change that to converge a solution. that's it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that this code "does not run"; it does not even compile. There are many mistakes in your code.

1. In `numHT()` you are using the result of `H_T()`; but `H_T()` returns `void`.
2. You are trying to break out of the infinite loop comparing the value of `tosses_amount` with `0`; but `tosses_amount` is assigned the value of `tossingtimes()` which is always greater than `0`.
3. Inside the `for` loop commented as `// random number generator` it looks like you are trying to use functions `heads_win()` and `tails_win()`; in fact, you are declaring new functions with these names.
4. You are never actually trying to compare the number of heads or tails you get with the number entered by the user.
5. You are only tossing the coin once (at the beginning of `main()`), and just reusing the same value over and over.

There are several other errors, but you may start with these.